# How to send a token from the iphone to rails backend?

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, devise, asihttprequest

When I'm asking the backend for a token with my username + password, it returns:

```
{"token":"5KB2bTHSSLgBeZjMqvfa"}
```

This is what I have working so far. I get the token, it is successfully saved.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    if ([request responseStatusCode] != 200) {
        [self requestFailed:request];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@", [request responseString]);
        NSData * data = [request responseData];
        NSDictionary *token = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error: nil];

        // authentication successful, store token
        NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setValue:[token objectForKey:@"token"] forKey:@"auth_token"];
    }
}
```

Now I want to send the token for every next request, but I don't know how. Can you tell me what's missing?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/userDetails"];    
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];

// AUTH TOKEN?
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: If the token is part of the URL, can't you just append it? Or does it need to be in a header?

Comment: Of course I could just append it, but then I would have to do this for every request. Is there a way to set it as a default parameter?

Comment: Btw, there's no reason for that `NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves`.

Answer (score 0):

ASI don't have special fields for "auth token". If you want to add this field to the request you can do that by:

1. Add it as post/get attribute
2. Add it as a header value `addRequestHeader:value:`

If you want to pass it to every request you can consider creating a "API Manager" or only "Authentication manager" singleton class.

Or maybe you may change it to HTTP Authentication:
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#handling_http_authentication

I would also consider using cookies - if your backend has possibility to return whole cookie object instead of token. ASI will handle session cookies.